# PL/SQL function to check if data in column is numeric

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have few tables which have varchar as data type for column but contains numeric values,
I wrote a pl/sql function for the same...but not working as intended.

```
create or replace FUNCTION is_column_numberic (table_name IN VARCHAR2, column_name in VARCHAR2)
   RETURN NUMBER
AS
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE('SELECT TO_NUMBER(nvl(' ||column_name|| ',0)) from ' ||table_name);
   RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      RETURN 0;
END;
```

for a column which does not contain numeric value, the function should return 0, but the function is returning 1 every time despite column containing numeric values.

Answer (score 3):

You have to return the value from the select into a bind variable, otherwise, no exception will be thrown:

```
    create or replace FUNCTION is_column_numberic (table_name IN VARCHAR2, column_name in VARCHAR2)
       RETURN NUMBER
    AS
    val NUMBER:
    BEGIN
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE('SELECT TO_NUMBER(nvl(' ||column_name|| ',0)) from ' ||table_name) 
  into val;
       RETURN 1;
    EXCEPTION
       WHEN OTHERS
       THEN
          RETURN 0;
    END;
```

I would also recommend fixing your tables to use proper data types.

Comment: You probably need to change the query to get `MAX(..)` or something or it'll get too-many-rows, unless the table only has one row. It's unclear whether it should return 1 if the table is empty - arguably the answer is 'unknown'...

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to catching an exception, in recent versions of Oracle (since 12c) you can use [the `validate_conversion()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html), which returns 1 for success and zero for failure:

```
create or replace FUNCTION is_column_numberic (table_name IN VARCHAR2, column_name in VARCHAR2)
   RETURN NUMBER
AS
   l_result NUMBER;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT MIN(VALIDATE_CONVERSION(' ||column_name|| ' AS NUMBER)) from ' ||table_name
   INTO l_result;
   RETURN l_result;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NhYYLaTS)

I've added `MIN()` around it so that if any value in the column cannot be converted then the overall result will be 0; if all values can then it will be 1. I have omitted the `NVL()` because if there are null values you can't really say if those are numeric or not, and it wasn't doing anything in your version anyway; but if you want to treat a column with no values at all as numeric or not numeric then you can do `NVL(MAX(...), 0)` - but with no data the answer is really 'unknown', so just returning null might be appropriate, as long as the caller knows what that means.

And as OldProgrammer said, you need an `INTO` clause - not having one is why your version isn't ever throwing an exception. [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/EXECUTE-IMMEDIATE-statement.html#GUID-C3245A95-B85B-4280-A01F-12307B108DC8__GUID-FC8D06AC-DEB9-47BA-81D4-47C93D82A382) says:

> **Note**: If *dynamic_sql_statement* is a `SELECT` statement, and you omit both *into_clause* and *bulk_collect_into_clause*, then *execute_immediate_statement* never executes.

The statement is still parsed, but the query is not executed - so it would report a syntax error (and return zero for all rows because of `when others` in your version), but it won't access the table data or try to convert any values, hence it not complaining about non-numeric values when you run your code.